# Get ExtensionValue from x509Certificate

Tags: certificate, hyperledger

I use bouncycastle in Java

```
CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", "BC")
certFactory.generateCertificate(in)
```

to generate the cert. It works fine. But when I use

```
x509Certificate.getExtensionValue("1.2.3.4.5.6.7")
```

The return value does not match the membersrvc's one.
Did I miss some thing?

Answer (score 0):

With bouncycastle you can do this to extract the ASN1 structure of the extension

```
public ASN1Primitive getExtensionValue(X509Certificate certificate, String oid) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = certificate.getExtensionValue(oid);
    if (bytes == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ASN1InputStream aIn = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    ASN1OctetString octs = (ASN1OctetString) aIn.readObject();
    aIn = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(octs.getOctets()));
    return aIn.readObject();
}
```

ASN1 is a complex object, you need to parse it to get the desired field. For example to Give back the CA URI meta-data found within the given X509 cert.

```
public String getIssuerURL(final X509Certificate certificate) throws Exception {

    final ASN1ObjectIdentifier ocspAccessMethod = X509ObjectIdentifiers.id_ad_caIssuers;
    final byte[] authInfoAccessExtensionValue = certificate.getExtensionValue(Extension.authorityInfoAccess.getId());
    if (null == authInfoAccessExtensionValue) {
        return null;
    }

    ASN1InputStream ais1 = null;
    ASN1InputStream ais2 = null;
    try {

        final ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(authInfoAccessExtensionValue);
        ais1 = new ASN1InputStream(bais);
        final DEROctetString oct = (DEROctetString) (ais1.readObject());
        ais2 = new ASN1InputStream(oct.getOctets());
        final AuthorityInformationAccess authorityInformationAccess = AuthorityInformationAccess.getInstance(ais2.readObject());

        final AccessDescription[] accessDescriptions = authorityInformationAccess.getAccessDescriptions();
        for (AccessDescription accessDescription : accessDescriptions) {

            final boolean correctAccessMethod = accessDescription.getAccessMethod().equals(ocspAccessMethod);
            if (!correctAccessMethod) {

                continue;
            }
            final GeneralName gn = accessDescription.getAccessLocation();
            if (gn.getTagNo() != GeneralName.uniformResourceIdentifier) {

                continue;
            }
            final DERIA5String str = (DERIA5String) ((DERTaggedObject) gn.toASN1Primitive()).getObject();
            final String accessLocation = str.getString();
            return accessLocation;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(ais1);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(ais2);
    }
}
```

To return a human-readable string from an ASN1Primitive

```
public String getStringFromGeneralName(ASN1Primitive names) throws IOException {
    ASN1TaggedObject taggedObject = (ASN1TaggedObject) names ;
    return new String(ASN1OctetString.getInstance(taggedObject, false).getOctets(), "ISO-8859-1");
}
```